# C program in netbeans

Tags: c

I'm new to writing C. I've installed NetBeans in my Windows laptop to write C programs. I'm trying to create a sample project and just write a `Hello World` program. However, it's showing the below error.

> cannot find include file stdio.h
>   For image see this link http://postimg.org/image/7lgeywe2l/9fa42dad/
>   I'm not sure how to solve this; how would I fix this?

Comment: instead netbeans i would suggest you to use [codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) imo its better than netbeans for c/c++

Comment: even are you sure you have configured netbeans with compiler properly, because netbeans by default doesnt configure c compiler

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/7lgeywe2l/9fa42dad/ Error image

Comment: I donno i configure c compiler. How to check it

Comment: That code should compile. It must be something wrong in the installation or configuration of NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

OK....

1. Do a search of your computer for the file `stdio.h`, just to see if it is installed on your system.  The file `stdio.h`, is one of many include files that are used by the compiler.  Include files contain function declarations as well as definitions of various constants.  It usually gets installed with either a compiler, or a part of a Software Development Kit (SDK).

1a.  If you are able to find `stdio.h`, then you need to configure netbeans, setting the path to where the file is found.  I am unable to give directions on how to do this, as I don't use netbeans.

1b.  If you don't find `stdio.h`, then you need to install a compiler, actually I recommend using mingw along with msys as an entry point.  You can read about mingw [here](http://www.mingw.org/), and msys [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).  Once these tools are installed, you really just need a simple text editor to write code, there are numerous ones out there.